Having trouble downgrading to an older, ESR version of Firefox and using the current profile
I'm trying to downgrade from Firefox 133.0 to Firefox ESR 128.5.2, and getting the dreaded "You've launched an older version of Firefox" message, which requires me to create a new profile or it won't start. When I create a new profile I cannot revert to the previous profile that contains all of my bookmarks, etc.
I followed the directions from this thread: How do I revert Firefox to a previous version and keep my profile intact? When I add --allow downgrade to the firefox.exe file (firefox.exe --allow downgrade), nothing happens when I double-click and try to run the program. (Also, when I changed the filename, a warning said the file would be unusable, but it was right). So I tried (firefox --allow downgrade.exe), and that didn't work either.
Since I am not a programmer, how do I add --allow downgrade to firefox.exe so it will run? Do I add it directly to the .exe file, create a shortcut, and add it to that, or something else?
I also deleted the compatibility.ini file and rebooted the PC, as another user recommended in the same post, but that didn't work either.
Can someone please explain how to revert to an older version of firefox and use the current profile?

If reusing the same profile does not work, try doing through Mozilla: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/switching-devices?utm_ content=switch-to-new-device

The CLI option is --allow-downgrade, not --allow downgrade. The answer you linked is proper too, it had a mistake in one place, which I corrected now. You can add it to the shortcut target in properties:

Of course, as the documentation states, the process may fail due to format inconsistencies anyways - in that case you can only compare the formats manually and adjust the profile yourself. But it should work the same between regular Firefox and the ESR version.

I've removed my comments now - perhaps you should remove the part in your answer about staying up to date, so as not to confuse future readers :p
